# AjaxControlToolkit v7.1213 dependencies have grown

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

The control toolkit now has new dependencies on System.Spacial, Microsoft.Data.Edm, Microsoft.Data.OData, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager and WindowsAzure.Storage!

Is this really necessary? Can I somehow bypass this bloat?

Comment: also asked here: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27600

Comment: I'm having the same concern - should I stick to an older version?

Comment: I've stayed with the old version. I find it remarkable how little conversation is happening on the interwebs regarding this. Maybe its time I do another round of searching, but so far its been months since I posed the question and I've heard nothing.
Glad to see you here, I don't feel so alone. ;)

Comment: Now I have 58mb of dependencies in my project.  Thanks Microsoft!

Comment: Maybe its time to take a look at this, released today: https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2015/03/09/announcing-the-asp-net-ajax-control-toolkit-v15-1.aspx

Answer (score 5):

The only solution I've found to avoid those unnecessary dependencies is to use the version before they introduced the dependencies.

In the Package Manager Console one can execute the following command to install the correct version:

```
Install-Package AjaxControlToolkit -Version 7.1005.0
```

I very much look forward to the day they remove all those unnecessary dependencies and this workaround solution becomes unnecessary!

Answer (score 0):

Released today (Mar 10, 2015):

> The ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit assembly is now free from external dependencies: it no longer requires AjaxMin, HtmlAgilityPack, or WindowsAzure. All functionality depending on third-party packages has been extracted to separate packages (ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit.StaticResources, ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer), all of which are available as Nuget packages.

[Found here](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2015/03/09/announcing-the-asp-net-ajax-control-toolkit-v15-1.aspx)